# How to allow user to select blank item in data bound ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox

I may have rather simple question, but I haven't found an answer to it. I have a ComboBox, which is bound to a BindingList. When the comboBox gets populated, there isn't a single item left blank. This feature would be though very appreciated.

Since I don't want to interefere with the BindingList I would like to somehow modify the ComboBox so there is always present a blank item on the top. I have already tried to insert an empty object on the first position but I got an exception saying that I cant modify dataBound comboBox.

Example Code:

```
public class Person{
    String Name {get; set;}
    Int Age {get; set;}
}

public class Client{
    void Main(){
        BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>()
        {
            new Person { Name = "Joe", Age = 25},
            new Person { Name = "David", Age = 48}
        }       
        comboBox1.DataSource = persons;     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Since you do not want to add a `null/empty` item to the original list, could you not simply “copy” the list, add the `null/empty` item to the copied list and use that list as a data source to the combo box?

Comment: If you don't want to show a pre-selected Item when the ComboBox is first loaded, set `comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;` right after you have set the DataSource (and its `DisplayMember`, at least: <= **before** you set the DataSource). -- (I assume your class sets `public` properties with real Types)

Comment: Consider putting a checkbox next to the combo and use that to allow the user to indicate "this setting is not set/ is set to X"

Answer (score 0):

Add a null value to the list:

```
persons.Add(null);
```

or add a line with an person with no name:

```
new Person {  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to avoid modifing the list, since there are another classes depending on it.

Comment: @Pepa: Yeah, but that's the only solution I've ever seen for this.  How big is the list?  As JohnG mentioned, you will probably need to create a copy of the list with an empty item as the first item (`new List()`, `Add(emptyItem)`, `AddRange(existingList)`)

Comment: @Pepa "since there are another classes depending on it" - not in the code posted!